# Fresh Install of Kubuntu, Grub won't load, boot repair fails

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, kubuntu

## Background

I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot this because I've run out of leads. I'm installing Kubuntu on a desktop that I built. I use Linux daily at work and I'm finally done with Windows on my main home machine. This desktop used to have Windows on it but I physically removed that storage. Kubuntu is installed over a Samsung SATA SSD which used to serve as an expansion drive. Obviously, there could be part compatibility issues with the hardware and the kernel but Kubuntu works fine when booted from the installation USB so I'm skeptical that's the issue. Who knows, someone out there might (probably, hopefully) know more than me on that account.

### Hardware

MOBO: Asus Prime z-370a
CPU: Intel i9 9900K
GPU: GeForce 2070 Super
MEM: 16x2 Corsair Vengance

## Problem

After installing Kubuntu 20.04.02 from the USB (full normal install, not dual boot, not partitioned, not LVM), the wizard prompts me to restart the computer, like normal. However, after the BIOs screen I get the Asus splash screen with no options and then... nothing. I can't access the grub and my only option is to either force shut down or CTL+AlT+DEL to go back to BIOs. In the BIOs, CMS is disabled, Secure Boot is disabled, and Fast Boot is disabled.

## Attempted Solution

I've installed Ubuntu/Mint/Kubuntu on about a dozen different laptops and usually if there are issues with booting you can fix them with the Boot Repair tool. This is the first time I'm not even able to get the GRUB to load though so maybe I'm not approaching it correctly. To run the tool I loaded Kubuntu from the USB installer and selected the Recommended Repair option. Unfortunately it presents me with an error message near the end of the process. The log can be found in the link to the PasteBin bellow.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xZRRSG6YNY/

I've also tried to use a NVMe SSD as the install location with the same result (I've since physically removed that from the machine). And I've tried reinstalling Kubuntu which did not result in any change.

Any ideas about what to try next would be much appreciated.

Comment: With UEFI and only one install, you have to press escape after UEFI/BIOS screen & before grub menu to get grub menu to appear. Sometimes multiple tries required. Did you install proprietary drives as that would be needed for nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. You can also try down arrow to load recovery mode, even if screen not shown. Error either from flash drive which can be ignored or because you left Windows fast start up on, and NTFS partition has hibernation flag set, preventing read/write using NTFS driver.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Didn't know about the ESC key and grub so that changes some things! Now when I try to boot from recovery, I get that familiar recovery menu and then it freezes... so that's different. I rebooted twice and both times it freezes after I move my cursor over a few options. I did select "install proprietary drivers" during the installation.

Comment: update: If I very quickly select "resume normal boot" I'm taken to the Kubuntu login screen. Then I can't log in because it freezes... does that maybe sound like a GPU driver problem?

Comment: Maybe, or perhaps some other setting in UEFI. I have both an old Asus z97 which required multiple settings in UEFI some optional. So I had to keep a list. My Gigabyte Z170 needs a couple of settings, similar to what you already posted. Have you updated UEFI from Asus, my z97 does not get any new updates, now.  And I installed a new NVMe SSD into my z170 and had to update NVMe firmware from Samsung with bootable ISO. Does it work in terminal mode from recovery boot? If you can run terminal command that would probably indicate a video issue.

Comment: Well this is going to make no sense but here it is... I was able to boot from the recovery mode menu by very quickly selecting the fsck option before it froze and then blindly clicking enter until it booted the OS. I was able to log in, update the system, and confirm that the NVIDIA drivers were present. (However, the resolution was awful for some reason.) I decided that I wanted to go back to installing this on the NVMe SSD since that was my original plan. I unplugged the SATA drives and reinstalled Kubuntu on the NVMe. So far I have had none of the issues that I experienced earlier...

Comment: It is the magic dust you sprinkled on it this time. That always works. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I faced this issue recently, it seems it still pops.

I was reusing a ssd to install a fresh machine. No other os involved.
All partitions removed from the ssd.

Tried all automatic, laptop would not boot.
Tried to create partitions by hand, laptop would not boot.

I used boot-repair. Same issue.

**So I ran gparted and looked more thoroughly.
I noticed the "boot" flag was not set on my ext4 partition.
Had to set it twice.**

Then the machine started ok.
The good old refurbished hp elitebook has a new happy user.

HIH